# Updating state value of a function that is called inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm rendering a function that returns a component in my react app like below

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.renderView()}
    <div>
  )
}
```

And my renderView is like below

```
 renderView() {
   return(
     <HelloPage
       pages={this.state.pageCount}
       showEndPage={true}
       renderResultStats={
         function (stats) {
           if (stats.numberOfPages < 5) {
             this.setState({
               pageCount: stats.numberOfPages
             })
           } else {
             this.setState({
               pageCount: 5
             })
           }
          }.bind(this)
        }
      />
   )
 }
```

I can get the code to work but I'm getting a console error as:

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state.

I would have used a variable instead of `setState` but I cannot get to pass the updated `pageCount` value to `pages` attribute as it just returns the default value. To overcome that problem I've used `setState`.

Comment: I suggest to move the inline function renderResultStats and have it as a method in the class, this.setState inside render method (or any render method called inside it) will always give this error

Comment: Does `pageCount` get used other than in `HelloPage component`? Could you share the code for HelloPage?

Comment: Yes. There's a similar component as `HelloPage component` and `pageCount` is used there as well

Comment: How about using componentDidMount to setState what you are trying to do inside the reder method?

Comment: Where are you calling `renderResultStats`? From the name of it, it looks like you are calling it inside the `render` function of `HelloPage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly update state in render function

**Option 1**

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState(state=>({pageNo:5}))
}
```

**Option 2**

```
render(){
  return(
    <HelloPage
                pages={this.state.pageCount}
                showEndPage={true}
                renderResultStats={()=>{this.setState(state=>({pageNo:5}))}}
     />
  );
}
```

this function not call automatically. and you can use any event method like `onClick`

Comment: How is your code different than OP's code besides using arrow function instead of a normal function?